# Can I run a 32-bit Win7 virtual machine from 64-bit Win8

Tags: windows, virtualbox, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am completely unfamiliar with virtual machines. I would appreciate guidance on (a) can I do this and (b) should I do this?

We were aiming to deploy a solution on Win8. We now realise that one of the tools we rely on is only supported on 32-bit OSes. Because we don't expect to use this tool frequently, might it be an option to run a virtual machine on Win8 that has 32-bit Win7 on it, and our 32-bit tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this with a Win 8.1 host, using (at various times) MS Hyper-V, VMware, and VirtualBox. Also MS Virtual PC under Win 7. It "just works". Do it. :)

Comment: Perhaps this belongs in a separate question... but what happens if you try to make the two machines (host + virtual) share the same network connection? Does that "just work" too? The tool we use is (in effect) a network sniffer.

Comment: @omatai In general: yes, they can use the same connection. But you may have difficulty if your app in the guest requires a special mode be set in the NIC. Most network sniffers that I know of have to put the NIC into promiscuous mode. This would have to be done to the _host's_ hardware NIC, even though it's a program running in the guest that's consuming all the packets (doing it only in the virtual NIC in the guest would of course not work). This is something you're going to have to test. btw, the difficulty here has nothing to do with having a 64-bit host and a 32-bit guest.